# Card widget gives error when I use fluter_stripe payment method in same page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-card

I am using `flutter_stripe` lib for integrating the Stripe payment method but it gives an error when I use Card widget with this lib.

My error is given as:

> "The name 'Card' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/material/card.dart (via package:flutter/material.dart)' and 'package:stripe_platform_interface/src/models/payment_methods.dart'.\nTry using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.",

Comment: I think you are create class with name 'Card' and stripe payment also using this name, try change your class name if this will not help, try remove one of this two imports

Comment: No, I am not using any Card named class, maybe flutter_stripe using this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found its answer by modifying the flutter_stripe import as
**import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart' hide Card;**